# Android. How to Dynamically add to a combined listview/scrollview using other activty

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have implemented androids swipe page with two fragments. One is an input page, where the user puts in a name and context and will have todays date as well as three radiobuttons.

The purpose is to add that information to the outpage page, the second tab, in a sort of listview. There will be a combined imageview with two textviews for each entry. The entire page should be scrollviewable so the user can get to previous entries.

How does one do this? Im not sure what to ask. I'm just asking for the right guidance here. I drew you guys a picture of what I'm looking for here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfmWa.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at CustomListAdapter, you can find examples easily anywhere on the web...

But i will give you an insight...

You will have:

An XML layout FOR EACH ROW OF THE LISTVIEW

That will look something like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Of course you have to add some rules to each one of this elements so they can look like the picture you drawed.

The custom adapter will look like this:

```
public class SearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<Track> tracks;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private static final String TAG = "com.example.ldurazo.xboxplayerexcercise.adapters.SearchAdapter";

    public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Track> tracks) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.tracks = tracks;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tracks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return tracks.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(view==null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.text.setText(tracks.get(i).getName());
        imageLoader.displayImage(tracks.get(i).getImageURL()+"&w=100&h=100",       holder.imageView);
        holder.text.setSelected(true);
        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView text;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

this was an example of one of my apps of course it wont look the same in yours but should be similar.

You add it programmatically in your oncreate or anywhere you want to have your data listed.

```
mListView.setAdapter(CustomAdapter).
```

You asked for a way to do it so my recommendation is for you to look up "Custom Base Adapter for Listviews" and try it.

Comment: Oh, and all that ViewHolder weird stuff is a design pattern for better scrolling in listviews.

Comment: So would I have to implement sharedpreferences since I want the list to be saved for future reference?

Comment: When you are talking about lists, or user data, you dont want to save them on shared preferences, use a DB instead, shared preferences are well used when you use them to store user preferences for your app (disable notifications, UI selection of the user, etc).

But yes you can do it with shared preferences.

Comment: by DB you mean a database? such as sql?

Comment: yes but it depends on the complexity of your app, sqlite can be used locally or a webservice depending on the size and business logic of your app.

If this is only for practice and will never go into production then yes, you can use sharedpreferences.